# 2 Routers 2 ISPs 1 DNS, Hiding DNS requests

Tags: networking, router, dns

Firstly I am going to explain my network topology.

I've got 2 routers serving separate ISPs and they are connected to each other via LAN and each one has its own dynamic IP and DNS by the ISP,

my Local network is one and it has the same subnet so I don't have any issues with the connectivity to serve each client (PC) with specific ISP.

I've decided to have the DNS from ISP(1) to serve the whole local network including ISP(2) clients, the reason I did that because I don't trust the DNS of ISP(2), and I don't want to use public DNS. everything is working perfect.

Q: Will ISP(1) DNS server administrator be able to see DNS requests from ISP(2) clients like this ISP(2-IP)+DNS request, or like this ISP(1-IP)+DNS request and hide ISP(2-IP)?

cheers.

Comment: How are you routing the different clients out the different connections?

Comment: I am using static ips for each client I need only to change the gateway ip which is the router IP in my case on the client side ..but with DNS server I am using ISP(1) router IP. for all the clients

Comment: Do you mean you have static routes for the ISP1 dns servers so requests go out of the ISP1  router regardless of whether the user is connected to ISP1 or ISP2?

Comment: there is no static routes, I just put in each client pc static DNS as the ip of router 1(ISP1). so yes all the DNS requests go out through ISP1

Comment: That isn't how it works - the default route dictates which router it goes out of in the absence of static routes.

Comment: so what you are saying is ISP1 DNS (default) in my case, would show for outside world, for example client on ISP2 IP + DNS request  for ISP1 adminstrator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that for the customers using ISP1 you have the ISP1 router as their default gateway, and then for ISP2 users you have the ISP2 router as their default gateway. And then you have all users set to use the DNS of ISP1

## Using the DNS Public IP address in clients

In this scenario, if anyone on the ISP2 router does a DNS query, the request will be forwarded out of the ISP2 router, but then go to the ISP1 DNS servers.  This will make the public IP of ISP2 be visible to the ISP1 DNS administrators, should they care about it enough to log queries.  The query will appear to them to come from an ISP2 IP address -  the public address of the ISP2 router.

It is also potentially observable by ISP2 as the queries will traverse their network.  They would need to be set up to be able to do this.

If you want to make sure the DNS queries are not visible to ISP2 at all, then add static routes to your clients such that the DNS servers of ISP1 are routed to the ISP1 router.  This way ISP1 will not see the ISP2 IP address sending queries to its DNS servers.

It is possible you can set these routes on your ISP2 router, however, this requires the router can route incoming packets back out the interface they arrived on (so they come into the ISP2 router, and are routed back to the LAN to the ISP1 router address.  Domestic routers are sometimes unable to do this.

Lets say the DNS server at ISP1 is 222.222.222.222

You would add a route saying

```
route 222.222.222.222 mask 255.255.255.255 gateway <ISP1 router IP address on LAN>
```

Add multiple routes if there are multiple servers.  If this doesn't work on the TP-Link, you can add a static route to each PC saying the same thing.

## Using the router IP address as the DNS server in clients

In the scenario where you use the router DNS IP address as the DNS server for clients, then no action needs to be taken.

DNS queries for ISP2 users are directed out of the ISP1 router to the ISP1 DNS server, and there is no interaction with ISP2 network resources. To ISP1 this will look the same as any other ISP1 DNS query even if they come from an ISP2 user.

Comment: I've got tp link routers for ISP 1 and 2, do you mean add static routes in router (2) ? can you please give me a simple example?

Comment: @Paul I think he is using his own router's IP address as the DNS server.

Comment: @David yes true

Comment: @Paul 222.222.222.222 it's my router's Ip address !!!!! can I use it ?

Comment: How have you set the ISP2 clients to use ISP1 router IP as their DNS?

Comment: @Paul yes I mentioned this in my first post.

Comment: *How* have you?  Exactly.

Comment: router 1: 192.198.0.1, router 2 : 192.168.0.2,  so client using ISP1 it's setting  192.168.0.3,255.255.255.0,192.168.0.1 DNS setting 192.168.0.1, so client using ISP2 its setting ip address 192.168.0.3,255.255.255.0,192.168.0.2 DNS setting 192.168.0.1

Comment: Ok great, in that case, you are already directing the DNS queries for ISP2 out of the ISP1 router to the ISP1 DNS server, so no need to do anything to shield this from ISP2.  And to ISP1 this will look the same as any other ISP1 DNS query even if they come from an ISP2 user.

Comment: @Paul but would it hide ISP2 public IPs to ISP1 ?

Comment: @testooo Yes it would as any interaction with ISP1 is via the ISP1 public address on the ISP1 router.

Comment: make it as a main answer and I'll mark it for you.

Comment: Great, I have added your scenario to the question, but left the original as it may be useful to others